# Joomla 3.0 component $params = $app->getParams();

Tags: class, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3.0 but at this point I can not use component because of a small problem.

This is the error, all other errors I could easily solve by adding Legacy to the class like this `JView` became `JViewLegacy`

However for the error beneath I couldn't find a solution:

Any help would be great!

The error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getParams() on a non-object in 
/var/www/g35003/mywebsite.nl/HTML/administrator/components/
com_taxonomy/taxonomy.php on line 16
```

The code line 16 is marked.

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

global $mainframe;
$params = $app->getParams();  /** <-- Line 16 */
require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');
$controller = new TaxonomyController();
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Answer (score 11):

`global $mainframe;` has been deprecated since Joomla 2.5 I believe. To get the parameters, you can use the following code:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_taxonomy');
$test = $params->get('param_name');
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a menu item of the component. This gets the component's global config values.

Comment: @AnriëtteMyburgh - Nothing was mentioned about menu items in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

$app    = &JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();  /** <-- Line 16 */
require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');
$controller = new TaxonomyController();
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Comment: this would be helpful http://www.themepartner.com/blog/56/get-joomla-17-plugin-module-component-and-template-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

For getting the menu item's params in my view I used the following:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication('site')->getMenu()->getActive();
$this->params = $menu->params;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, the user has not specified anything about menu items. Also, if you read his error, you will see `/administrator` in the path of the file, therefore what you've provided had nothing to do with the backend component view